# iPhone: Increase volume

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have got an audio file which is quite quiet.
I'm playing it using `AVAudioPlayer`, but I can barely hear anything, especially without headphones.

***Is there a way to increase the volume of an audio record?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [volume](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/volume) property for that. If even at it's highest setting the volume is still too low, I think you should edit the media file in some kind of music editor (i.e. [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)) and increase the volume there.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do it programatically in my app.

Comment: You can try setting the volume to value greater then 1 but I think Iphone will ignore it because it could damage your speakers if you could set this to anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

`player.volume = 2.0;`

The doco says that volume is "nominally" between 0 and 1.0,
which seems to suggest that you can overdrive it.

Good luck, and try not to accidentally deafen users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use SpeakHere Apple Sample, as I did. To increase audio volume on this sample you need to set Player to Speaker Mode.

Add this code in AQPlayer.mm:

```
OSStatus error;
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker; 
error = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
if (error) printf("couldn't set audio speaker!");
```

Before this code:

```
XThrowIfError (AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0), "set queue volume");
```

Maybe it's to late but, I hope it helps.